# How to resize the Bootstrap DatePicker?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

My code is like this :

HTML :

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker no-padding" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="input-medium" size="16" type="text"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        startDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

Demo : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/hous9y5L/72/)

I want to change the size of the bootstrap **datepicker**

Any suggestion to solve my problem

Thank you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can control the width using `.datepicker` and `.table-condensed` selectors:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: new Date()
  });
});
```

```css
.datepicker,
.table-condensed {
  width: 500px;
  height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div class="input-append date datepicker no-padding" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="input-medium" size="16" type="text"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

You need to apply both because `.table-condensed` has `max-width:100%`. if you get rid of this you can control the size using `.datepicker`

Comment: @T J, Thank you very much. I'ts working. I want ask again. Whether it can change the datepicker height?

Comment: @mosestoh increasing will work fine, I updated the example. However it has a minimum height around 200px to display those many rows... at 200px you'll have to remove the padding from `<td>`s. If you want to go below that you'll have to do further customization like changing the font sizes

Comment: @T J, Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Here is the magic spell that worked well for me. And it does well in most browsers.

```
.datepicker,
.table-condensed {
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    font-size: x-small; 
}
```

Basically, it displays a scaled down size of the bootstrap datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just wanted to give the same height to the date input as the other inputs have. This line solved it:

```
$('input[type="date"]').height($('input').height());
```