# How resize filed input datetime in bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I decided to change dashboard selected period rage datetime.
I chose bootstrap-datetimepicker.

```js
$(function () {              
                $("#datetime_input").datetimepicker({
                    locale: 'ru'
                });
                $("#datetime_output").datetimepicker({
                    locale: 'ru'
                });
   });
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <span>C</span>
        <div class='col-xs-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetime_input'>
                    <input id="INPUT_DATETIME" type='text' class="form-control" value="${INPUT_DATETIME}"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span>По</span>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetime_output'>
                    <input id="OUTPUT_DATETIME" type='text' class="form-control" value="${OUTPUT_DATETIME}"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How resize field input datetime in bootstrap-datetimepicker?
[image]
For example how reduce field input datetime?

[image]

How to eliminate the resulting difference?

p.s.
I found some question

- [How to resize the Bootstrap DatePicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941412/how-to-resize-the-bootstrap-datepicker)
- [Reduce size and change text color of the bootstrap-datepicker field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404620/reduce-size-and-change-text-color-of-the-bootstrap-datepicker-field)

BUT proposed solution not work for my case.

Comment: please fix errors in your snippet...

Comment: fixed, absent </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. May be you want to implement date range picker in your dashboard with bootstrap datetime picker.So, if it is like that then the below link is useful to you.

Link : http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Use the below code :

```
 <div class="row">
    <span>C</span>
    <div class='col-xs-3'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetime_input'>
                <input id="INPUT_DATETIME" type='text' class="form-control"  value="${INPUT_DATETIME}"/>
                <span id="input_pick" class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span>По</span>
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetime_output'>
                <input id="OUTPUT_DATETIME" type='text' class="form-control" value="${OUTPUT_DATETIME}"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Add CSS code :

```
 #INPUT_DATETIME{
   width : 177px;
 }
 #input_pick{
  width: 37px; 
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
 }
```

Comment: For example how reduce field input datetime?

Comment: reduce means in which context?

Comment: I add jpg: the distance from the last digit to the icons I want to reduce.

Comment: Ok, so if your design is not responsive then give fix width to input datetime element and span that is used to pick date give it to float : left

Comment: Please specify your answer

Comment: ok give below styles to your elements :

1 .  <input id="INPUT_DATETIME" type='text' class="form-control" value="${INPUT_DATETIME}"/>

width: 177px;

2.   <span class="input-group-addon">

    width: 37px;
    height: 34px;
    float: left;

Comment: <input id="INPUT_DATETIME" type='text' class="form-control" value="${INPUT_DATETIME}"   style=" width: 177px;"/>

<span class="input-group-addon" style="    width: 37px;    height: 34px;    float: left;">

Comment: hope you are getting. :-)

Comment: How to eliminate the resulting difference? look next picture in question

Comment: try to increase width of text box.